# Having big trouble deploying Ionic app to the phone

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I've had this bug that's been bothering me for months. 
Its about relatively complex social app built with Ionic.

What works:

-Running Inside browser
-Running inside Ionic DevApp on the phone

Whats not working:
-Deploying app to the device and building apk

Here is the Ionic info, run command and stack trace error I get:

```
$ ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.2.7 (C:\Users\Jasko\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, browser 6.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 23 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.8

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (e:\Android\SDK)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10




$ ionic cordova run android
[INFO] Hardware device(s) found for android. Using --device.
> ionic-app-scripts.cmd build --target cordova --platform android
[22:16:01]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.3
[22:16:01]  build dev started ...
[22:16:01]  clean started ...
[22:16:01]  clean finished in 11 ms
[22:16:01]  copy started ...
[22:16:02]  deeplinks started ...
[22:16:02]  deeplinks finished in 542 ms
[22:16:02]  transpile started ...
[22:16:08]  transpile finished in 5.85 s
[22:16:08]  preprocess started ...
[22:16:08]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms
[22:16:08]  webpack started ...
[22:16:08]  copy finished in 6.90 s
[22:16:13]  webpack finished in 5.02 s
[22:16:13]  sass started ...
[22:16:15]  sass finished in 1.42 s
[22:16:15]  postprocess started ...
[22:16:15]  postprocess finished in 19 ms
[22:16:15]  lint started ...
[22:16:15]  build dev finished in 13.39 s
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/providers/loading.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/providers/logout.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/validator.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/providers/video.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/login/login.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/update-contact/update-contact.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/users/users.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/reported-post/reported-post.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/image-modal/image-modal.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/user-info/user-info.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/search-people/search-people.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/new-message/new-message.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/messages/messages.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/add-members/add-members.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/new-group/new-group.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/groups/groups.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/requests/requests.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/friends/friends.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/add-post/add-post.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/comments/comments.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/tabs/tabs.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/verification/verification.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/trial/trial.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/login.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/video-call/video-call.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/app/app.component.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pipes/friend.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pipes/search.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pipes/conversation.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pipes/date.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pipes/group.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/app/app.module.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/app/main.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/add-post/add-post.module.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/comments/comments.module.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/reported-post/reported-post.module.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/timeline/timeline.module.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/users/users.module.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/providers/data.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/providers/image.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/providers/login.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/providers/firebase.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/group/group.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/providers/alert.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/providers/country-code.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/home/home.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/message/message.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/group-info/group-info.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
Tried to lint E:/Projects/TheApp/RealMe/src/pages/timeline/timeline.ts but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration.
[22:16:17]  lint finished in 2.79 s
> cordova.cmd build android --device
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to E:\Projects\TheApp\RealMe\platforms\android\app\build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to E:\Projects\TheApp\RealMe\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\app-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to E:\Projects\TheApp\RealMe\platforms\android\app\build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to E:\Projects\TheApp\RealMe\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\app-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
Preparing Firebase on Android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=e:\Android\SDK (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=e:\Android\SDK (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Configure project :app
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 27.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\Projects\TheApp\RealMe\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 132

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No match found

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
E:\Projects\TheApp\RealMe\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\Projects\TheApp\RealMe\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 132

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No match found

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --device exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !

**EDIT**: config.xml added

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="1" id="com.xxx.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>xxx.Me</name>
    <description>xxx.Me</description>
    <author email="xyz@gmail.com" href="#">Ionic</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="~0.8.8" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="~3.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="~5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="~3.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativeaudio" spec="~3.0.9" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="~2.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="~5.4.4">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="24.1.1+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="~1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-audioinput" spec="~1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="~2.5.0">
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="xxx" />
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="xxx" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="7.0.0">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.1040008853766-xxx" />
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11.8.0" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^3.0.1">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100" sessionid="3d82ea13" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.5" />
    <engine name="android" spec="7.1.4" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Can you show us the `config.xml` file of your project. Specifically the parts that list the plugins and the setting for `android-versionCode`

Comment: do you have android studio? if yes . open the project in android studio go to build.gradle(module) and change all 'compile' with 'implementation' 'TestCompile' to 'TestImplementation'. and try to run using android studio

Comment: config.xml added. I would rather not use AndroidStudio to run the app as it is auto generated code that changes every time. android-versionCode="1"

Comment: @andypotato config.xml added

Comment: Can you try removing the android-versionCode=“1” property from the <widget> tag and retry building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to migrate everything to AndroidX
After I open AndroidStudio and chose Refactor-Migrate AndroidX everything run smoothly